# Is there any PDF command, that scales rectangle coordinates?

Tags: pdf, itext

I have an application, that extracts text and rectangles from pdf files for further analysis. I use ItextSharp for extraction, and everything worked smoothly, until I stumbled upon a document, which has some strange table cell rectangles. The values in the drawing commands, that I retrieve, seem 10 times larger, than actual dimensions of the latter rectangles.

Just an example :

2577 831.676 385.996 3.99609 re

At the same time, when viewing the document all rectangles seem to correctly fit in the bounds of document pages. My guess is that there should be some scaling command, telling, that these values should be scaled down. Is the assumption right, or how is it possible, that such large rectangles are rendered so, that they stay inside the bounds of a page ?

The pdf document is behind this link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/gyvon0dwk6a9cj0/prEVS_ISO_11620_KOM_et.pdf?dl=0

The code, that handles extraction of dimensions from PRStream is as follows :

```
private static List<PdfRect> GetRectsAndLinesFromStream(PRStream stream)
    {
        var streamBytes = PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(stream);
        var tokenizer = new PRTokeniser(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(streamBytes));
        List<string> newBuf = new List<string>();
        List<PdfRect> rects = new List<PdfRect>();
        List<string> allTokens = new List<string>();

        float[,] ctm = null;
        List<float[,]>  ctms = new List<float[,]>();


        //if current ctm has not yet been added to list
        bool pendingCtm = false;


        //format definition for string-> float conversion
        var format = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();
        format.NegativeSign = "-";

        while (tokenizer.NextToken())
        {

            //Add them to our master buffer
            newBuf.Add(tokenizer.StringValue);

            if (
                tokenizer.TokenType == PRTokeniser.TokType.OTHER && newBuf[newBuf.Count - 1] == "re"
                )
            {
                float startPointX = (float)double.Parse(newBuf[newBuf.Count - 5], format);
                float startPointY = (float)double.Parse(newBuf[newBuf.Count - 4], format);
                float width = (float)double.Parse(newBuf[newBuf.Count - 3], format);
                float height = (float)double.Parse(newBuf[newBuf.Count - 2], format); 

                float endPointX = startPointX + width;
                float endPointY = startPointY + height;

                //if transformation is defined, correct coordinates
                if (ctm!=null)
                {
                    //extract parameters
                    float a = ctm[0, 0];
                    float b = ctm[0, 1];
                    float c = ctm[1, 0];
                    float d = ctm[1, 1];
                    float e = ctm[2, 0];
                    float f = ctm[2, 1];

                   //reverse transformation to get x and y from x' and y' 
                    startPointX = (startPointX - startPointY * c - e) / a; 
                    startPointY = (startPointY - startPointX * b - f) / d; 
                    endPointX = (endPointX - endPointY * c - e) / a;
                    endPointY = (endPointY - endPointX * b - f) / d; 
                }

                rects.Add(new PdfRect(startPointX, startPointY , endPointX  , endPointY ));
            }
            //store current ctm
            else if (tokenizer.TokenType == PRTokeniser.TokType.OTHER && newBuf[newBuf.Count - 1] == "q")
            {
                if (ctm != null)
                {
                    ctms.Add(ctm);
                    pendingCtm = false;
                }
            }
            //fetch last ctm and remove it from list
            else if (tokenizer.TokenType == PRTokeniser.TokType.OTHER && newBuf[newBuf.Count - 1] == "Q")
            {
                if (ctms.Count > 0)
                {
                    ctm = ctms[ctms.Count - 1];
                    ctms.RemoveAt(ctms.Count -1 );
                }
            }
            else if (tokenizer.TokenType == PRTokeniser.TokType.OTHER && newBuf[newBuf.Count - 1] == "cm")
            {

                // x' = x*a + y*c + e ; y' = x*b + y*d + f
                float a = (float)double.Parse(newBuf[newBuf.Count - 7], format);
                float b = (float)double.Parse(newBuf[newBuf.Count - 6], format);
                float c = (float)double.Parse(newBuf[newBuf.Count - 5], format);
                float d = (float)double.Parse(newBuf[newBuf.Count - 4], format);
                float e = (float)double.Parse(newBuf[newBuf.Count - 3], format);
                float f = (float)double.Parse(newBuf[newBuf.Count - 2], format);

                float[,] tempCtm = ctm;

                ctm = new float[3, 3] {
                {a,b,0},
                {c,d,0},
                {e,f,1}
                };

                //multiply matrices to form 1 transformation matrix
                if (pendingCtm && tempCtm != null)
                {
                    float[,] resultantCtm;
                    if (!TryMultiplyMatrix(tempCtm, ctm, out resultantCtm))
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid transform matrix");
                    }
                    ctm = resultantCtm;
                }
                //current CTM has not yet been saved to stack
                pendingCtm = true;
            }     
        return rects;
    }
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of the the Current Transformation Matrix (CTM)? If not, I suggest that you start reading ISO-32000-1, because you are completely ignoring all transformations that may exist in the graphics state at the moment the path of a rectangle is constructed.

Comment: Concerning the edited code: I doubt that the handling of `pendingCtm` is correct. Furthermore your handling of **re** indicates that you only have considered matrices which scale and translate but not those that rotate or skew. After such transformations you need more than 2 points to correctly describe the resulting quadrilateral.

Comment: Ok, I see, I somehow missed chapter 8.3.3. If I got it right, then it should be sufficient to treat rectangles as parallelograms and reconstruct them using 4 points. Or translation, scaling, skewing and rotation should be handled separately ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `cm`. Did you read [The ABC of PDF with iText](https://leanpub.com/itext_pdfabc/)? The book isn't finished yet, but you can already download the first five chapters.

This is a screen shot of the table that shows the `cm` operator:

[image]

This is an example of 5 shapes that are created *in the exact same way*, using identical syntax:

[image]

They are added at different positions, even in a different size and shape, because of the change in the graphics state: the coordinate system was changed, and the shapes are rendered in that altered coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks a lot!The initial problem got solved very fast after reading Your answers.Still I have a feeling, that I misunderstood the CTM multiplication thing: "If a series of transformations is carried out, the matrices representing each of the individual transformations can be multiplied together....". Currently I just take every new CTM definition as entirely new CTM and drop the previous one, and it seems to work. But the document says, they should sometimes be multiplied. So how do I tell, if there is a "series of transformations"? Should the commands be one right after another in this case?

Comment: Did you read the part about the `q` and the `Q` operators. Most of the times, the current state is saved before performing a transformation. Then when the state is restored, you go back to the initial situation. We do this, so that we don't get lost in transformations. That's why you can drop the CTM in most of the cases, **but** you shouldn't count on that to be true always: you need to take into account the `q` and `Q` operators.

Comment: My assumption also is that the OP ignores **q** and **Q**. When implementing them he should furthermore not try to use short cuts again, though, **Q** does not simply always reset to the identity matrix but to the matrix active at the time of the matching **q**.

Comment: The idea of saving states on stack and being able to fetch certain state is clear. However, did I get it right, that "cm" command in most cases follows  "q", which saves previous state on stack, and when "q" is followed by numerous "cm" commands, the CTMs are then multiplied to form a resultant transformation matrix ?

Comment: It is not *mandatory* that a `cm` is preceded by a `q`. I wouldn't count on that to be true. However, it's a common practice.

Comment: Really sorry for wasting your time, but could you please review the updated code? The results are now way better, but there are still some occasional artifacts, and a few documents, which hint, that I have interpreted something the wrong way.